# Oracle: Detecting change from a view without a last modified date

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a reliable way to detect change on an entire row output of a view where no reliable modification date exists and the total length of the row exceeds the maximum varchar2 length?

(table & view names changed to protect the innocent and the guilty)

**Things I cannot control or influence**
There is a view *uu_big_view* that is built from lots of underlying tables. The underlying tables are refreshed on an unknown schedule, have no history and have no indication of when their data was refreshed. The output columns of *uu_big_view* are a mixture types: number, varchar2, date, and nvarchar2. If all of the columns a row of *uu_big_view* were concatenated together, e.g. a || b || c ||..etc, the total length would be in excess of 50,000 characters.

**Things I have built and can control**

1. I have a table *uu_big_view_reference* that has the same structure as *uu_big_view* with the following additions:
   load_date Date
   ,refresh_date Date
   ,row_hash RAW(160)

**My problem**
How do I detect changes to records that exist in *uu_big_view_reference* but are different?
I **must** check every column except for the primary key for changes. Nothing less than the entire row will suffice.

I have a MERGE prepared but...

MERGE into uu_big_view_reference tgt
Using uu_big_view src
On (src.primary_key = tgt.primary_key)
When Matched Then
*oh crap! How do I figure out if the data has been updated?*
When Not Matched Then
*easy! Just insert the new data*;

...I have no way to detect modification based on a date anywhere. I also cannot concatenate the row values together as they would exceed the 4000 character maximum of an nvarchar2.

**Things I have tried**

1. Standard_Hash( col1 || col2 || col3 ||...etc.)
   Failed because the total length of col1+col2+col3 exceeds 4000k for some rows
2. Posting on StackOverflow

**Things I know will work but hope I don't have to do**

1. An 80-line (one line for each column in common between *uu_big_view* and *uu_big_view_reference*) CASE statement, i.e.
   CASE
   When uu_big_view.col1 <> uu_big_view_reference Then *update uu_big_view_reference*
   When uu_big_view.col2 <> uu_big_view_reference Then *update uu_big_view_reference*
   ...etc.

Comment: you can call standard_hash on a CLOB.  use DBMS_LOB to build a CLOB of the columns